# Activate Virtual Enviroment using Python Code

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I m using Windows 7, I wanted a way where I could run my python file and it would execute my virtual environment.
I have read the following commands

```
activate_this_file = "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py"
execfile(activate_this_file, dict(__file__=activate_this_file))
```

I need to know what is `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/` and what is `activate_this.py`? Anyone know better solution for this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Hi Klaus,I wanted to use multiple virtual envoronments based on some conditions.It is like running "workon" command on windows using python script

Comment: That's not a problem, that's *your* solution to it.

Comment: I wanted the script so as how to activate my virtual environment using python code in .py file?

Answer (score 1):

`/path/to/virtualenv/bin/` is the path to the virtualenv you want to activate. For example, if you have run `virtualenv xyzzy` in directory `/home/dheeraj/venv` the path is `/home/dheeraj/venv/xyzzy/bin/`.

`activate_this.py` is an activation script created by `virtualenv`.